# How I can get price of custom token(in usd) using web3js library having contract?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

Is there an existing methods to get price of custom token using web3js library and have contract on this token?

Comment: Price of a token can be determined from different sources (decentralized/centralized exchanges). Are you interested in any specific source? Otherwise the question is probably too broad.

Comment: Defi.Usd.Like in bscscan